# Should I be testing for an AdalException inside an ActionFilter?

Tags: azure-active-directory, adal, action-filter

In some Azure Samples on GitHub [like this one](https://github.com/ahelland/AADGuide-CodeSamples/blob/master/ClaimsWebApp/Controllers/UserProfileController.cs#L30-L50) we have an example of using ADAL to access a protected Web API resource. The effort is protected by a try/catch looking for an AdalException

I'll summarize the code as thus:

```
 try 
 { 
     //pseudo code...  configure a client to use an access token..
     var token = ADAL.AcquireTokenAsync...
     var httpClient = new HttpClient(baseUri, token);

     // use the token for querying some protected API
     var result = //await HttpClient to return data...

     return View(result); 
 } 
 catch (AdalException) 
 { 
     // do something important with the exception, 
     // e.g. return an error View w/login link
 }
```

So, as I start to flesh out my MVC controllers to use ADAL-access_token'd requests, do I really want all this try/catch business in every controller?

Does it make sense to create an `ActionFilter`? This snippet was inspired by code I saw at [this Azure Sample](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-dotnet-graphapi-web/blob/master/WebAppGraphAPI/Controllers/ContactsController.cs#L32-L65)

```
public class AdalErrorAttribute : FilterAttribute, IExceptionFilter
{
    void IExceptionFilter.OnException(ExceptionContext filterContext)
    {
        if(filterContext.Exception is AdalException)
        {
            if (filterContext.RequestContext.HttpContext.Request.QueryString["reauth"] == "True")
            {
                //
                // Send an OpenID Connect sign-in request to get a new set of tokens.
                // If the user still has a valid session with Azure AD, they will not be prompted for their credentials.
                // The OpenID Connect middleware will return to this controller after the sign-in response has been handled.
                //
                filterContext.RequestContext.HttpContext.GetOwinContext().Authentication.Challenge(
                    new AuthenticationProperties(),
                    OpenIdConnectAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**My Context:**
I'm taking a rather homogenous set of scaffolded MVC controllers that were EntityFramework-centric at the time they were generated.. but now need to be re-tooled to access my Web API (via my new AutoRest client)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@vibronet made a good point - *don't* do that for your WebAPI endpoints.  They're called with bearer auth, and shouldn't be automatically redirected to a sign-in process.  Give back a 401 indicating the credentials are invalid and let it go.

But for an MVC app the user is using interactively, this is a reasonable idea to follow, subject to a couple of constraints.

1. Make sure your filter is very tight about what it matches.  Ie. make sure it's *only* handling exceptions you can reasonably-certainly draw to an authentication issue (vs. being an access-denied issue).  Perhaps a custom exception that gets thrown by your wrapping logic, or some extra conditions beyond it being an ADALException to make sure it's an issue solveable by logging in again.
2. Unless you really want *every* request have this handling, look at attaching it at the controller or action layer instead of globally.
3. Look out for potential "loop" issues, where you get an error, tell the user to log in again, get the error, make them log in again, etc.  Maybe set some data in the session when triggering the login, or in the login process, or something like that.  Better to give an error message than get the user's browser stuck in an infinite-redirect loop.  (of course, this applies to the manually-handle-the-exception case too)

Hope that helps.

Comment: Good thoughts. will definitely be doing #2, thanks for the pointers.

Comment: The samples mentioned don't perform automatic redirect- rather, they modify the UX so that the user is offered a link to trigger the authentication process. The idea is that the inability to perform a call from a given controller doesn't necessarily mean that the user cannot do anything else with the app. Great example of this approach: klout.com

Answer (score 2):

There are two issues with the approach.

1. the sample code you mention and the filter implementation are for web APPs, not web API. That's an important difference. Web APPs can rely on the browser to interact with the user for authentication; web APIs don't know what UX the client has (or even if there's any UX at all) hence the error behavior is radically different
2. a controller might call multiple APIs, requiring multiple token requests for different resources- which can fail or succeed independently, and connect to different providers. Different controllers might call different resources. The reaction to the error might vary. A filter such as the one you prototyped would only help with a very narrow set of cases.
   Hence I would say that unless your controllers are all expected to perform very homogeneous logic, a filter such as the above would not give you the flexibility you need.

Comment: added a bit of context to the end of my question.. In short: yes, indeed, I'm dealing w/MVC controllers. Good point about calling multiple APIs. Thx!!